# Edit a foreign key's fields in a template

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I'm unsure of how I can edit a foreign key's fields from the template of another model - my changes do not update the model on post, see below.

models

```
class Projects(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class Current(models.Model):
    fk_user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fk_project = models.ForeignKey(projects, default='1', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

views

```
class current(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):

    model = Current
    fields = [
    'fk_project'
    ]
    template_name = 'users/current.html'
    context_object_name = 'current'


    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.fk_user = self.request.user
        form.save()
        # return super().form_valid(form)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.request.path_info)

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.fk_user:
            return True
        return False
```

current.html

```
<form method="POST">{% csrf_token %}

<input type="text" value="{{ current.fk_project.name }}"/>

<button type="submit">post</button>
```

Comment: Missing `</form>`?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you amend form_valid to follow the usual conventions. No idea if this will fix it, but

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    instance = form.save( commit=False)
    instance.fk_user = self.request.user
    instance.save()
    # return super().form_valid(form)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.request.path_info)
```

If the desire is to update fields in the Project which is identified by the form as well as to store it in the `Current` instance which is the subject of this UpdateView, you can accomplish this by adding appropriate non-Model fields to the form and then processing the data in form_valid. For example, to pick a project, link it as at present, and simultaneously update its name:

```
class CurrentAndProjectUpdateForm( forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Current
        fields = ['fk_project', ]

    name = forms.CharField( ...)   # new name for the related project

class current(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):

    model = Current                          # don't think this now necessary
    form_class = CurrentAndProjectUpdateForm  #  because it's implicit in this form
    # fields =                                # DEFINITELY not needed here now

...

    def form_valid(self, form):
        instance = form.save( commit=False)
        instance.fk_user = self.request.user
        instance.save()

        project = instance.fk_project
        project.name = form.cleaned_data['name']
        project.save()

        # return super().form_valid(form)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.request.path_info)
```

Comment: Corrected, but this doesn't change anything it appears. I still cannot edit the model that the foreign key points to.

Comment: @Game_analysis You can't do that without a bit more code.  I'll update my answer.